# How do I convert a wstring to a NSString

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c

I tried `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)(myWString.c_str())]` but that returns a single character string.

This is on the iPhone by the way, if that matters any :)

Answer (score 9):

Within the Apple compiler the size of `wchar_t` is 4 bytes, so `std::wstring` are encoded in UTF32 and not in UTF16 as in Microsoft and other compilers.

```
std::wstring sCpp = L"hello";
NSString * sObjC = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:sCpp.data()
                                            length:sCpp.size() * sizeof(wchar_t)
                                          encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```